# Sublime regular expression to match wx.data.xxx but not wx.data.yyy

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

I want to find all instances where

`wx.data.xxx`

but not

`wx.data.update` OR `wx.data.get`

I tried `(wx.data.)[^update][^get]` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use negative lookahead instead of a negative character set:

```
wx\.data\.(?!update|get)[^.\n]+
```

https://regex101.com/r/chy79T/1

Answer (score 1):

You could use `(?!` [negative lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) asserting what is on the right is not get or update.

`\S+` matches 1+ times a non whitespace char. If you don't want to match a dot and a whitespace as well, you could use `[^.\s]+`

```
\bwx\.data\.(?!get|update)\S+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/StxLzv/1)

If for example updates or gets is allowed, you could add a word boundary `\b`

```
\bwx\.data\.(?!(?:get|update)\b)\S+
```